# magento 2: save product error after upgrade from 2.0.7 to 2.1.3

Tags: magento2, product, database, adminhtml

After upgrading from 2.0.7 to 2.1.3 I am unable to alter any products in the admin.

After going to

1. Products > Catalog > Select a product
2. Update a field and Save product

I receive the following sql error after clicking save:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entity_id' in 'NEW', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_int` (`row_id`,`attribute_id`,`value`,`store_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `row_id` = VALUES(`row_id`), `attribute_id` = VALUES(`attribute_id`), `value` = VALUES(`value`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`)
```

Not really sure how to debug this, let me know if you have any ideas or sugguestions to gather more information.

Comment: Run `composer update`, `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`,`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`,`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`, `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: @AnkitShah I ran all these commands but they did not resolve issue

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
php bin/magento indexer:set-mode realtime
```

This should solve sql error, go into admin and confirm if product can be saved.  Once product successfully saves, revert indexer mode back to schedule and reindex

```
php bin/magento indexer:set-mode schedule
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```